# Getting error 404 for put request (using express and node js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm more or less new to web development and I've had trouble getting a PUT request to go through. We've set up a database and succeeded in getting GET and POST requests work but we keep getting a 404 error with trying to send a PUT request.

```
router.put('/edit-beverage/:id', (req, res) => {

    console.log(`Updating beverage on id ${data.params.id}:`);
    let data = req.body;

    query1 = `UPDATE Beverage `
    query1 += `SET name = '${data.nameInput}', abv = ${data.abvInput}, breweryID = ${data.breweryID_FK}, categoryID = ${data.categoryID_FK} `
    query1 += `WHERE beverageID = ${data.params.id};`

    db.pool.query(query1, (err, rows, fields) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Here's what we have on another page.

```
let express = require('express');   // We are using the express library for the web server
let app = express();            // We need to instantiate an express object to interact with the server in our code
PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;;                 // Set a port number at the top so it's easy to change in the future
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// Cors should allow access from extrernal addresses.
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

// Database
const db = require('./database/db-connector')

/*
    ROUTES
*/
// create new Router instance for api routes
// mount the router on the app
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
module.exports = app;

let router = require('express').Router();
```

And this is what I try to send on Postman. [As far as I can tell, the endpoint is the same as what's on the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTtKt.png)

Would anyone be able to tell me what's going on? I'm confused as to why the server isn't recognizing the request as a proper path.

Comment: endpoint in express is `/edit-beverage/:id` ... your request `/edit-beverage/?id=9` .... I thought it would need to be `/edit-beverage/9` ... as per [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Comment: I didn't know it had to be arranged like that for a put request. Appreciate your help! Not sure why but when I put id as a value in Postman, '?id=9' automatically pops up.

Comment: When using a framework like Express, you should familiarise yourself with [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Comment: `router.put('/edit-beverage/:id'` catch id in `req.params.id`. In postman you are specifiying id in `req.query.id`.